# Collapse grep results into one line while keeping unique values and removing duplicate values?

Tags: bash, awk, grep, zsh, xargs

I'm using `zsh` but open to a `bash` solution as well. Suppose I have the following command:

```bsh
ls **/*/assessment(.) | xargs egrep "(^  \[\./.*\]$|^    input = .*$)"
```

Which gives me an output that resembles this:

```
<path-01-to>/assessment:  [./input_file_01]
<path-01-to>/assessment:    input = 'input_file_01.i'
<path-02-to>/assessment:  [./input_file_02]
<path-02-to>/assessment:    input = 'input_file_02.i'
<path-02-to>/assessment:  [./input_file_02b]
<path-02-to>/assessment:    input = 'input_file_02b.i'
<path-03-to>/assessment:  [./input_file_03]
<path-03-to>/assessment:    input = 'input_file_03.i'
```

I would like to collapse lines so each (`[./title]` `input`) pair are on the same line. Thus the expected output would look like this:

```
<path-01-to>/assessment:  [./input_file_01] input = 'input_file_01.i'
<path-02-to>/assessment:  [./input_file_02] input = 'input_file_02.i'
<path-02-to>/assessment:  [./input_file_02b] input = 'input_file_02b.i'
<path-03-to>/assessment:  [./input_file_03] input = 'input_file_03.i'
```

I've looked at using `tr -d "\n"` but it combines everything into one line. I'm thinking `awk` or a different language might be better suited for this.

**Edit:**

Here is an example of an input file `assessment`:

**path/01/to/assessment**:

```
[Tests]
  [./input_file_01]
    type = RunApp
    input = 'input_file_01.i'
  [../]
[]
```

**path/02/to/assessment**:

```
[Tests]
  [./input_file_02]
    type = RunApp
    input = 'input_file_02.i'
    cli_args = 'blah blah'
  [../]
  [./input_file_02b]
    type = CSVDiff
    input = 'input_file_02b.i'
  [../]
[]
```

Comment: @EdMorton Good point, I shouldn't parse the output of `ls`. I've updated my queston to include a few examples of assessment files.

Comment: You probably need awk here. Something like `awk '/^  \[\.\/.*\]$/ || /^    input = .*$/{a[FILENAME] = a[FILENAME] " " $0} END { for (f in a) print f": " a[f]}'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work using any awk in any shell on every UNIX box:

```
$ awk '/^ *\[\.\//{title=$1} /^ *input =/{print FILENAME ":", title, "=", $NF}' */*/assessment
01/to/assessment: [./input_file_01] = 'input_file_01.i'
02/to/assessment: [./input_file_02] = 'input_file_02.i'
02/to/assessment: [./input_file_02b] = 'input_file_02b.i'
```